# Is he using a theorem for real numbers, on a complex power series?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

This is from Rudins principles of mathematical analysis.

First are theorems 3.41 and 3.42 which he uses later.

I assume that 3.41 holds for complex numbers? But what about 3.42?, complex numbers does not have an ordering, and the b's are ordered so I assume it must be for real numbers?

[image]

Now he is going to use the 3.42 n a complex power series:

[image]

Is this a valid proof? I mean he write c=b, but complex numbers does not have an ordering, but in 3.42 he used an ordering. He also write $z^n=a_n$, but in 3.42, does he not assume that $a_n$ is real?

Is it that it is a power series with real coefficients?, is that what he means? If so there is only the problem that $a_n=z^n$, is this allowed considering $z^n$ may be complex?

Comment: I think that $|z|$ actually is a real number. In fact, there are a lot of theorems that apply with multiple variables (and complex numbers are a particular case of two variables).

Comment: In thm 3.42 $a_n$ can be complex.

Comment: Yes this is valid, actually, each time the author uses an ordering, the quantities are assumed to be real valued (this concerns b_n in 3.42 and c_n in 3.44, but not a_n there, which can be complex valued).

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain to me how the first inequality in the proof of 3.42 occurs?

Comment: I think I understand now. In the proof of 3.42 he uses the triangle inequalty for complex numbers and splits everything up. But since every b is positive, he may so combine everything again, and he just chose to write it in an absolute value sign?(The hypothesis of 3.42 requires all b's to be positive?)

Answer (score 1):

All numbers here are complex unless indicated otherwise. When an inequality between two numbers appears in the statement of a theorem, that is an indication that they are assumed real.

The first inequality of 3.42 would be better written without absolute value sign. It is just the triangle inequality combined with the estimate $|A_n|\le M$:

$$\begin{split}
&\left|\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} A_n(b_n-b_{n+1})+A_qb_q-A_{p-1}b_q\right|
\\& \le 
\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} |A_n(b_n-b_{n+1})|+|A_qb_q|+|A_{p-1}b_q | \\
&\le 
\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} M(b_n-b_{n+1}) +M b_q +M b_q  
\end{split}$$